# if $a^b=b^a$,then $ab$ and $e^2$ which is bigger?

Tags: functions

if $a^b=b^a, 0<b<a$  then $ab$ and $e^2$ which is bigger?

I try $$b^a=a^b\Longrightarrow a\ln{b}=b\log{a}\Longrightarrow \dfrac{\ln{a}}{a}=\dfrac{\ln{b}}{b}$$,where $\ln{x}=\log{x}=\log_{e}{x}$

consider the function
$$f(x)=\dfrac{\ln{x}}{x},x>0,\Longrightarrow f'(x)=\dfrac{1-\ln{x}}{x^2},x>0$$if $f'(x)=0$,then $x=e$.

[image]

Comment: I did not understand a single word. What is $e$ ?

Comment: $e=2.718\cdots$...

Comment: @G. Fougeron Well I think that $e$  is the Napier's constant

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: "consider the function ... if f′(x)=0,then x=e" Right, and then what? I mean, you "considered" this function for a reason, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions $0<b<a$ to the identity $a^b=b^a$ can be parametrized by $x>0$ as $$b:=(1+1/x)^x\qquad a:=(1+1/x)^{x+1}$$
hence $$\sqrt{ab}=(1+1/x)^{x+1/2}$$
The "*Note*" to the question  [Find the smallest $a>0$ such that $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+a}>e$ for all $x\geq 1\,$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929252/find-the-smallest-a0-such-that-1-frac1xxae-for-all-x-geq-1) (valid for $x>0$) shows that $$(1+1/x)^{x+1/2}>e$$
Thus, $$\sqrt{ab}>e$$